Callout component not displaying correctly using React Native Maps
Basically the Callout component is always being cut does not matter what I put inside of it.
Example:

The code:
<MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        style={{
          width: 300,
          height: 400,
        }}
        zoomControlEnabled
        showsUserLocation
        showsMyLocationButton
        showsBuildings={false}
        showsIndoors={false}
        showsPointsOfInterest={false}
        loadingEnabled>
        <Marker
          coordinate={{
            latitude: -20.213090469552533,
            longitude: -40.266256965125116,
          }}
          pinColor={'red'}>
          <Callout>
            <View style={{padding: 10}}>
              <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>Olá</Text>
            </View>
          </Callout>
        </Marker>
      </MapView>

I was expecting to at least show some text inside of it but nothing worked so far.

Could you please check this if it's helpful?

Are there any updates on this? I am experiencing the same issue
