React Native Maps Custom Marker Not working
How to customize the Map Marker in react native maps? its displaying nothing when I click on the Marker. its not showing the Callout component . and also, its not allowed to Override Marker Styles, and it refuse to override WIDTH and HEIGHT as I want.
          <Marker key={city.id} coordinate={{ latitude: city.latitude, longitude: city.longitude }}><View style={{width:120 , height: 30}}>Hello</View></Marker>     

See the react native maps marker width and height styles are not overriding

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try with Callout
import  { Callout, Marker } from "react-native-maps"
const customeIcon = require("path_to_icon");

const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = React.useState();

<Marker
  key={city.id}
  coordinate={{ latitude: city.latitude, longitude: city.longitude }}
  image={customeIcon}
  onPress={() => setSelectedCity(city)}
>
  <Callout tooltip>
    <TouchableHighlight><Text>Hello</Text></TouchableHighlight>
  </Callout>
</Marker>

{ selectedCity && <YourCityDetailsComponent /> }


Callout is not working either. I found the same issue in following link that um facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79141450/callout-component-not-displaying-correctly-using-react-native-maps
